# javascript object item name

Tags: javascript, this

I have following javascript code:

```
var oReg = new Object;
oReg.a = {size: 762, content: 0};
oReg.b = {size: 342, content: 0};
//...

for (var s in oReg) {
    oReg[s].set = function(i) {
        alert('#name of oReg item#: ' + i);
    }
}
```

Where is "#name of oReg item#" should be a, b etc
I think it should be begin with `this`, but I cant make it out.

Comment: And your question is..?

Comment: instead of "#name of oReg item#" should be "s", but you cant write "s" because the variable does not exists in the function itself, only in the loop

Comment: @andrew The variable does exist outside the loop, but it will always point to the last key when `set` is invoked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be `s` instead of `i`, but unfortunately it isn't that simple because of the "[infamous loop problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1451009/javascript-infamous-loop-problem)". You have to create a new scope on each iteration (functions create scopes), to be able to keep a reference to each value of `s`. Otherwise, your setter will always return the value of the last object key.

The following code should do it:

```
for (var s in oReg) {
    oReg[s].set = (function(key) {
        return function() {
            alert('#name of oReg item#: ' + key);
        }
    }(s));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know lots of people will start to cry seeing a call to `eval` in code, but that's really only dangerous when throwing user input into it. Therefore:

```
var oReg = new Object;
oReg.a = {size: 762, content: 0};
oReg.b = {size: 342, content: 0};

for (var s in oReg) {
    eval("oReg[s].set = function(i){alert('oReg."+s+": ' + i);}");
}
```

Comment: *"that's really only dangerous when throwing user input into it"*... you are right, but there are other reasons for avoiding `eval`: it's slow, more difficult for the compiler to optimize and the code is harder to maintain.

Comment: Comments accepted, I guess I learned something today again :) Take bfavaretto's answer instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
var oReg = new Object;
oReg.a = {size: 762, content: 0};
oReg.b = {size: 342, content: 0};
//...

for (var s in oReg) {
    oReg[s].set = (function(s) {
        alert('#name of oReg item#: ' + s);
    })(s);
}
```

I think you trying do this.

Comment: This will alert on each iteration, and `set` will be undefined for every key.